# python increment operator has weird behavior in one line conditional statement

Tags: python, increment

Why does `idcter` not reset to 0 when it exceeds `maxid`?

```
maxid=9999
idcter=9999
idcter += 1 if(idcter <= maxid) else 0
print('this is good: ' + str(idcter))

idcter += 1 if(idcter <= maxid) else 0
print('now this is weird: ' + str(idcter))

idcter=10000
idcter = idcter + 1 if(idcter <= maxid) else 0
print("that's better: " + str(idcter))
```

Output:

```
this is good: 10000
now this is weird: 10000
that's better: 0
```

So it's a simple fix, but why would idcter not reset after it exceeds `maxid`?

Comment: Which line are you confused by?

Comment: Are you just expecting that `+= 0` will do the same thing as `= 0`? If it did, that would make `+=` very unpredictable and hard to use…

Comment: If you think about it, it's impossible for `idcter += 1 if idcter <= maxid else 0` to set the variable `idcter` to 0. Even if that statement would be parsed as `(idcter += 1) if idcter <= maxid else 0`, neither of the two `if` branches assigns 0 to `idcter`. The `idcter += 1` branch increments it, and the `0` branch does nothing. There is no assignment in that branch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The operator precedence of

```
idcter += 1 if (idcter <= maxid) else 0
```

is visualized by the following grouping

```
idcter += (1 if (idcter <= maxid) else 0)
```

which means you **increment by** `0` if the condition doesn't hold.

Compare that to

```
idcter = idcter + 1 if (idcter <= maxid) else 0
# ==
idcter = (idcter + 1) if (idcter <= maxid) else 0
```

Where you **assign** `0` **to the result** in the same case.

BTW, `10000` already exceeds your `maxid` of `9999`. One typical way to implement such a resetting increment uses the modulo operator. In your case:

```
idcter = (idcter+1) % (maxid+1)  # 9997 -> 9998 -> 9999 -> 0 -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Additional thanks for the modulo tip!